# Export an Array of specific slides in powerpoint to a PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, powerpoint

I made a virtual lab in powerpoint for highschool students, once in a while there is a slide where they are asked a question. They can leave their answer in a Textbox.

At the end i want to insert a button that contains a macro which will save only the slides on which there was a question to a PDF file. The other slides are irrelevant for the teacher.

In short: I am trying to make a PowerPoint macro where I can save a selection of slides as a PDF. Its not a range of slides, but a selection of slides.

Currently i have this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim mySlides As Variant
Dim PR As PrintRange
Dim savePath As String
Dim myInput As String

'Add the name of the student in the file name
myInput = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox2").OLEFormat.Object.Text

'Location of saved file
savePath = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & myInput & " Antwoorden Virtueel Lab" & ".pdf"

If ActivePresentation.Slides(9).Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Text = "PRARDT" Then

mySlides = Array(9, 11, 15)

Set PR = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(mySlides)


ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Path:=savePath, _
FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, _
PrintRange:=PR, _
Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, _
FrameSlides:=msoTrue, _
RangeType:=ppPrintSlideRange

Else: MsgBox "Does not work"

End If

End Sub
```

However its not working

If I want to do it with a range of slides than i can use this code (Which does work):

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'This function saves the last slide as a PDF file with a time stamp and the users name who completed the induction.
Dim PR As PrintRange
Dim savePath As String
Dim myInput As String

myInput = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox2").OLEFormat.Object.Text

'Location of saved file
savePath = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & myInput & " Antwoorden Virtueel Lab" & ".pdf"

If ActivePresentation.Slides(9).Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Text = "PRARDT" Then
    With ActivePresentation.PrintOptions
    .Ranges.ClearAll ' always do this
    Set PR = .Ranges.Add(9, 21)
    End With

ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Path:=savePath, _
FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, _
PrintRange:=PR, _
Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, _
FrameSlides:=msoTrue, _
RangeType:=ppPrintSlideRange

Else
MsgBox "something went wrong"

End If


End Sub
```

This macro does work, but i can only print a range of slides with it or 1 specific slide. I want to print an Array of specific slides to PDF. I have looked at related questions on this topic however i am such a big noob that i can't fix my problem even with their closely related examples.

Comment: One simpleminded approach would be to save a temporary copy of the current presentation, step backwards through the Slides collection, deleting any slide that doesn't meet your criteria, then save the result to PDF.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg That could work, however the total amount of slides is 350 so that would be very tedious (especially since about 20 students do the assignment and thus all make a different file It is such an amount of slides, because there are 10 different paths a student can take, depending on what they do in their assignment. The students have to organise different DNA-elements and put them in the right order. Depending on which order they use, they are send to a different slide using a simple If textbox = ... then view slide ... All other paths become irrelevant after their assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I did it! I finally found where the error's came from and now have a working macro

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim myInput As String
Dim savePath As String

'Name of Student
myInput = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox2").OLEFormat.Object.Text

'Location of saved file
savePath = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & myInput & " Antwoorden Virtueel Lab" & ".pdf"  

'Select path student took
If ActivePresentation.Slides(9).Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Text = "PRARDT" Then

'Change view
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit

'Prevents error 
ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate

'Select specific slides
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(9, 11, 15)).Select

'save selected slides as PDF
ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat Path:=savePath, FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, RangeType:=ppPrintSelection

MsgBox "file saved"

Else
MsgBox "wont work"

End If

End Sub
```

Now i ll make 9 different if then and select which slides need to be saved for  for each path.